# placing strings from a string vector into main string

Tags: c++

I want to place strings from a string vector to a string. here's the code I have tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* event = "this is %s, %s and %s";
    std::vector<string> strs = {"sam", "joey", "chandler"};
    char buffer[200];

    std::vector<string>::iterator it;

    for(it = strs.begin(); it < strs.end(); it++)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, event, it->c_str());
    }

    std::cout << buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

the result i expected is it will replace %s flags in event strings with strings inside strs vector. however i got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

can you please point out my mistake.

**EDIT**

the length of the vector is variable. I have a template of strings with variable number of `%s` flags and I am trying to write a function where we can pass a vector and replace those flags with strings in vector.

example of these strings are:
"hello %s, meet %s"
"welcome %s"
"today is %s, and we want %s to work with you"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is that `printf` is plain inappropriate for what you want to do. I suggest simple substring `"%s"` search and replace. It's easy enough and surely safer.

```
std::string formatter(const char* event, const std::vector<string> &strs) {
    std::string buffer(event);

    size_t off = 0;
    for (auto placeholder : strs) {
        size_t i = buffer.find("%s", off);
        if (i == std::string::npos)
            break;

        buffer.erase(i, 2);
        buffer.insert(i, placeholder);
        off = i;
    }

    return buffer;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << formatter("this is %s, %s and %s", { { "sam", "joey", "chandler" } }) << "\n";
    std::cout << formatter("welcome %s", { { "sam", "joey", "chandler" } }) << "\n";
    std::cout << formatter("today is %s, and we want %s to work with you", { { "sam", "joey", "chandler" } }) << "\n";
}
```

Produces

```
this is sam, joey and chandler
welcome sam
today is sam, and we want joey to work with you
```

Comment: This is correct approach. To handle the situation when number of `%s` in the target string is less number of items in the vector, there can be one more check after the `for` loop.

Comment: @SameerManek See below for the vector included version

Answer (score 2):

aCraig5075 has the right approach I think.  Here's something similar that utilizes the vector:

```
int main()
{
    std::string event {"this is %s, %s and %s"};
    std::string flag = "%s";
    std::vector<std::string> strs = {"sam", "joey", "chandler", "fred"};
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = strs.begin();
    std::size_t found = event.find(flag);
    while (it != strs.end() && found != std::string::npos) {  //terminates at shortest
        event.replace(found, flag.length(), *it);
        found = event.find(flag);
        ++it;
    }
    std::cout << event << std::endl;
}
```

This will play nicely if there is a mismatch between the number of flags in the string and the number of strings in the vector, halting the loop if either is exhausted.

Comment: thanks. I think I will go with Craig's solution, but this also seems to be a good solution. I'll try this out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make three separate calls to `sprintf`, but in each call you're passing it three `%s` conversions, so the first time it tries to print out three strings, even though you've only passed one. If it finished executing the first iteration, on the second iterations you'd do the same thing again: pass one string, but tell it to expect three. Same again the third time.

It's not at all clear to me why you'd do any of this though. You can produce the output you seem to want with code on this order:

```
std::vector<string> strs = {"sam", "joey", "chandler"};
std::cout << "This is: " << strs[0] << ", " << strs[1] << " and " << strs[2];
```

Comment: What if the user wants to add n strings to a "formatting" string? Please do address that in your answer.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar: Then you might want to consider something like an `std;:ostream_iterator` to stream out the items, each followed by a separator of your choice.

Comment: i want to do this because I have several string templates with variable number of flags. i am writing a function that will replace these flags with strings by passing only 1 vector.

Comment: @SameerManek: In that case, I'd ask a new question giving a detailed description of what you want, and asking how to do it. I don't think the approach you're taking so far is likely to lead toward a useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [usage of sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), and if you want to continue to use your code format, my approach is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const char* event = "this is %s, %s and %s";
    std::vector<string> strs = {"sam", "joey", "chandler"};
    char buffer[200];

    sprintf(buffer, event, strs[0].c_str(),strs[1].c_str(),strs[2].c_str());

    std::cout << buffer<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP has variable vector length. This does not address that.